# How to avoid automatic casting provided by Play Framwork Json Reads but get an exception instead

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

Reads appears to do auto cast for me if the casting is possible. e.g., Float -> Int. For example, if the code gets json as following,

```
{
"name": "Jack",
"age": 22.4,
"role": "Coder"
}
```

the instance of class Person would have field age of 22 instead of getting an invalid argument exception. If I do want an exception in that case, what's the best solution? thx a lot.

```
case class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val role: String)

object Person {
implicit val residentReads: Reads[Resident] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String](minLength[String](3)) and
  (JsPath \ "age").read[Int](min(0)) and
  (JsPath \ "role").readNullable[String]
)(Resident.apply _)

...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code, we can see why. Any value matching a `JsNumber` has `toInt` called upon it:

```
implicit object IntReads extends Reads[Int] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
        case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(n.toInt)
        case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(ValidationError("error.expected.jsnumber"))))
    }
}
```

To avoid this, we can implement a new `Reads[Int]` that will not validate non-integers:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.data.validation._

implicit object WholeIntReads extends Reads[Int] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
        case JsNumber(n) if(n.isValidInt) => JsSuccess(n.toInt)
        case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(ValidationError("error.expected.jsnumber"))))
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
case class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val role: String)

object Person {
    implicit val residentReads: Reads[Person] = (
        (JsPath \ "name").read[String](minLength[String](3)) and
        (JsPath \ "age").read[Int](WholeIntReads keepAnd min(0)) and
        (JsPath \ "role").read[String]
    )(Person.apply _)
}
```

(There were some inconsistencies in your sample code, so I fixed them to make this compile. The only relevant line is `age`.)

**Results:**

```
scala> Json.parse("""{"name": "Jack","age": 22.4,"role": "Coder"}""").validate[Person]
res13: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Person] = JsError(List((/age,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsnumber,WrappedArray())))))

scala> Json.parse("""{"name": "Jack","age": 22,"role": "Coder"}""").validate[Person]
res14: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Person] = JsSuccess(Person(Jack,22,Coder),)

scala> Json.parse("""{"name": "Jack","age": -22,"role": "Coder"}""").validate[Person]
res15: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Person] = JsError(List((/age,List(ValidationError(error.min,WrappedArray(0))))))
```

Note that I'm using `validate[T]` and not throwing an exceptions, as this is best practice. This will allow the `ValidationError`s to accumulate and be handled without needing any exceptions.